# Issue starting out with xlwings - AttributeError: Excel.Application.Workbooks

Tags: xlwings

I was trying to use the package `xlwings` and ran into a simple error right from the start.  I was able to run the example files they provided [here](http://xlwings.org/examples/) without any major issues (except for multiple Excel books opening up upon running the code) but as soon as I tried to execute code via IPython I got the error `AttributeError: Excel.Application.Workbooks`.  Specifically I ran:

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart
wb = Workbook()
Range('A1').value = 'Foo 1'
```

and got

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-7-7436ba97d05d> in <module>()
          1 from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart
    ----> 2 wb = Workbook()
          3 Range('A1').value = 'Foo 1'

    PATH\xlwings\main.pyc in __init__(self, fullname, xl_workbook, app_visible)
        139         else:
        140             # Open Excel if necessary and create a new workbook
    --> 141             self.xl_app, self.xl_workbook = xlplatform.new_workbook()
        142 
        143         self.name = xlplatform.get_workbook_name(self.xl_workbook)

    PATH\xlwings\_xlwindows.pyc in new_workbook()
        103 def new_workbook():
        104     xl_app = _get_latest_app()
    --> 105     xl_workbook = xl_app.Workbooks.Add()
        106     return xl_app, xl_workbook
        107 

   PATH\win32com\client\dynamic.pyc in __getattr__(self, attr)
        520 
        521                 # no where else to look.
    --> 522                 raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
        523 
        524         def __setattr__(self, attr, value):

    AttributeError: Excel.Application.Workbooks
```

I noticed the examples have a .xlxm file already present in the folder with the python code.  Does the python code only ever work if it's in the same location as an existing Excel file?  Does this mean it can't create Excel files automatically?  Apologies if this is basic.

Comment: What version of xlwings are you using?

Comment: @FelixZumstein Using 0.3.5

Comment: This looks similar to another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349050/xlwings-workbook-call-returns-attributeerror-open-application?noredirect=1#comment46997274_29349050)  that I couldn't yet replicate. Do you mind to open an issue [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues) to continue the discussion? otherwise these conversations tend to become a bit too  long for stackoverflow.